# Object Variable or with block variable not set and FocusRowChanged gridview does not display images accordingly in vb.net

Tags: gridview, devexpress, picturebox, system.io.file

Please solve the problem "Object variable or With block variable not set" whether this is because there is an empty database column or something else. FocusRowChanged gridview does not display images accordingly. You can see the screenshot below showing an image that doesn't match the blue circle when I move to another row. For the record I used a visual studio 2010.

thanks
jack

```
    Private Sub GridView1_FocusedRowChanged(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As FocusedRowChangedEventArgs) Handles GridView1.FocusedRowChanged
         Dim view As GridView = TryCast(sender, GridView)
If e.FocusedRowHandle <> GridControl.InvalidRowHandle Then
            Dim SUBFOLDERP As String = view.GetFocusedRow("SUBFOLDERP").ToString
           If SUBFOLDERP IsNot Nothing Then
                Dim Filename1 As String = view.GetFocusedRow("FILENAME1").ToString
                Dim Filename2 As String = view.GetFocusedRow("FILENAME2").ToString
                Dim Filename3 As String = view.GetFocusedRow("FILENAME3").ToString
                Dim Code As String = view.GetFocusedRow("CODE").ToString
                Dim filePath1 As String = DevExpress.Utils.FilesHelper.FindingFileName(parentpathimage & "\" & SUBFOLDERP & "\", Filename1, False)
                Dim filePath2 As String = DevExpress.Utils.FilesHelper.FindingFileName(parentpathimage & "\" & SUBFOLDERP & "\", Filename2, False)
                Dim filePath3 As String = DevExpress.Utils.FilesHelper.FindingFileName(parentpathimage & "\" & SUBFOLDERP & "\", Filename3, False)
                If Not String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(filePath1) Then
                    PictureEdit1.Image = Image.FromStream(New MemoryStream(File.ReadAllBytes(filePath1)), True, False)
                    If Not String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(filePath2) Then
                        PictureEdit2.Image = Image.FromStream(New MemoryStream(File.ReadAllBytes(filePath2)), True, False)
                        If Not String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(filePath3) Then
                            PictureEdit3.Image = Image.FromStream(New MemoryStream(File.ReadAllBytes(filePath3)), True, False)
                        End If
                    End If
                End If
            End If
        End If

    End Sub
```

[image: Object Variable or with block variable not set]

[image: does not display images accordingly]
[image: variable not set 16-03-2022]

Comment: `Dim SUBFOLDERP As String = view.GetFocusedRow("SUBFOLDERP")?.ToString()` -- You should not nest those `If` conditions. -- You should also check beforehand whether `e.FocusedRowHandle <> view.InvalidRowHandle`

Comment: @Jimi , This problem arises because optionsview ShowAutoFilterRow = True if I set false There's no such problem

Comment: @Jimi , but I still need AutoFilterRow

Comment: @Jimi , I've updated the code according to your recommendations but there is an error `'DevExpress.XtraGrid.Views.Base.ColumnView.InvalidRowHandle' is not accessible in this context because it is 'Protected'

Comment: It's probably `GridControl.InvalidRowHandle`.

Comment: @Jimi , still error `Object variable or With block variable not set.`

Comment: Did you add the Elvis as describe in the example in my first comment? As in `[...] = view.GetFocusedRow("SUBFOLDERP")?.ToString()`. Did you see that symbol that represents a *question mark*? -- Note that I don't have any DevExpress stuff here, I have to rely on my memory of it.

Comment: @Jimi , `The '?' character cannot be used here` error in my version visual studio 2010

Comment: Gosh, VS 2010! That's very old. Then you need something like `Dim SUBFOLDERP = view.GetFocusedRow("SUBFOLDERP") '[...] If SUBFOLDERP IsNot Nothing then Dim filePath1 As String = [...] If Not String.IsNullOrEmpty(filePath1) then PictureEdit1.Image = [...] End If End If`. Repeat for the other parts. -- Note that [Visual Studio Community Edition](https://visualstudio.microsoft.com/vs/community/) is free software. VS 2010 is too old, you'll find a lot of code sample that use language features that were not available at that time.

Comment: @Jimi , I've updated the code according to your recommendations but it's still a problem

Comment: That's not what I suggested. Read again my previous comment. Those lines of code are *repeated for the other parts*. You're only testing `SUBFOLDERP`for null, you need to do the same with all the other values (`FILENAME1` etc.). -- You still have a nested `If` after; that also, as mentioned, needs to be removed: one of those `If` condition, separated, for each Column.