# The Image of a PictureBox doesn't appear in a new Form, which should close when deactivated

Tags: vb.net, image, winforms, picturebox

The Image of a PictureEdit or PictureBox is not shown in a new form (`Form2`).
Also, this new Form should auto-close when clicking on a different Control in the parent form (form1).

With my code, only the third Image appears when I double-click on an Image in Form1.

Is there a solution so that I do not need to create 3 new forms according to the number of images in Form1?.

For the record, I use Visual Studio 2010

```
Public Class Form1
   Private Sub PictureEdit1_DoubleClick(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles PictureEdit1.DoubleClick
        Dim yourForm As New Form2()
        yourForm.ShowDialog()
    End Sub

    Private Sub PictureEdit2_DoubleClick(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles PictureEdit2.DoubleClick
        Dim yourForm As New Form2()
        yourForm.ShowDialog()
    End Sub
    Private Sub PictureEdit3_DoubleClick(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles PictureEdit3.DoubleClick
        Dim yourForm As New Form2()
        yourForm.ShowDialog()
    End Sub
End Class

Public Class Form2
    Private Sub Form2_Load(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
        Dim Form_One As Form1 = CType(Application.OpenForms("form1"), Form1)
        Me.PictureEdit1.Image = Form_One.PictureEdit1.Image
        Me.PictureEdit1.Image = Form_One.PictureEdit2.Image
        Me.PictureEdit1.Image = Form_One.PictureEdit3.Image
    End Sub
End Class
```

[image: picturedit1,picturedit2,picturedit3 from form1]
[image: result picturedit1 from form2]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Small changes required:

- Add a constructor to your Form2 that accepts an Image as argument.
- Override `OnDeactivate`, to close the Form when you click *outside* of it.
- Use `Show(Me)` instead of `ShowDialog()`: this will make the calling Form the Owner of Form2, so it stays on top of its owner, but it's not a Modal Window, which is not deactivated when you click outside of it.

```
Public Class Form1
   ' [...]
   Private Sub PictureEdit1_DoubleClick(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles PictureEdit1.DoubleClick
        Dim f2 As New Form2(PictureEdit1.Image)
        f2.Show(Me)
    End Sub
    ' [...]
End Class

Public Class Form2
    Public Sub New()
        Me.New(Nothing)
    End Sub
    Public Sub New(img As Image)
        InitializeComponent()
        PictureEdit1.Image = img
    End Sub

    Protected Overrides Sub OnDeactivate(e As EventArgs)
        MyBase.OnDeactivate(e)
        BeginInvoke(New Action(Sub() Close()))
    End Sub
End Class
```

Comment: Thanks for your response, it went perfectly.

Comment: [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71433449/object-variable-or-with-block-variable-not-set-and-focusrowchanged-gridview-does) . I have another post maybe you can help you?

Answer (score 1):

Once you've made the changes suggested by Jimi, you can also use ONE sub to handle all three PictureEdit controls by listing more than one control/event after the "Handles" keyword:

```
Private Sub PictureEditAll_DoubleClick(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles PictureEdit1.DoubleClick, PictureEdit2.DoubleClick, PictureEdit3.DoubleClick
    Dim picEdit As PictureEdit = DirectCast(sender, PictureEdit)
    Dim f2 As New Form2(picEdit.Image)
    f2.Show(Me)
End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks for your response, it went perfectly.